# passing a complete loop to bootstrap modal

Tags: laravel

I want to edit multi select for which i want to pass two loops to 
   bootstrap modal and their i want to compare id's and on that basis i will select already selected record my button

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal{{ $value->id}}">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
</a>
```

my form

```
<div class="form-group">

    <select name="upsubject[]" multiple class="form-control">

     @foreach($subject as $data)

          @foreach($value->subject as $key)

              <option value="{{$data->id}}" <?php if ($key->id == $data->id)

{echo 

"selected";}

?>>{{$data->name}}</option>

            @endforeach

        @endforeach

    </select>
</div>`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<option {{ ($key->id == $data->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $data->name }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to detach the selected and than select new records as i am updating subjects but the above logic give me same subject three times each